# Keras модель с несколькими входами, сравнение результатов на выходе

Tags: машинное-обучение, keras

Добрый день возникла проблема при создании модели с двумя несколькими входами на Keras, мне нужно сравнить изображение исходное с изображение искаженным прошедшим ряд преобразований, есть ли в keras слой сравнения или что нибудь что сможет мне помочь, и можно ли в keras загружать на эти входы два разных набора данных, заранее спасибо[image: упрощенная схема модели]

Answer (score 0):

Слоя совпадения нет. Это можно решить так:
На вход подавать в .fit модели изображения одинаковые, а на выход единицу. После подавать изображение в негативе и необработанное, на выход 0.